# Mange Tout/Peas & Courgettes/Marrows

Tags: variety-selection, terminology, zucchini, peas

Is a *mange tout* merely an immature *pea* and there's nothing more to it than that? And while we're at it, is a *courgette* (zucchino for Americans & Italians) just an immature *marrow* and that's all?

Does variety come into it?

Answer (score 3):

If *mange tout*<sup>1</sup> is the same as what we call a "snap pea" or a "snow pea", it's not that it's immature, it's a different variety. (Well, I generally eat them before the peas fatten up, so they *are* immature, but I don't do this with "garden peas" (aka "English peas") because the pods aren't very tasty.)

Hmm... what's a *marrow*? It looks like a member of *C. pepo*, but an image search turns up all kinds of wildly different squashes.

---

<sup>1</sup> That's French for "eat [it] all" -- I guess my French is better than my [British] English?